# One-way chat which encode messages, this is the server side

Tags: python, tkinter, socket, caesar-cipher, chat

This is one of my first real projects in python. It's basically a one-way chat where the server sends away an encoded message. The logic of it is pretty simple and I know there is some unnecessary code in there. I have also made a simple client who receives the messages and decrypts it, based on if the user input == the decrypted version of the password. Would love to get some tips on how I could improve it.

So initially the program was supposed to encrypt a message the user enter, then create a password and encrypt that password. Then it would store this data in a text file, with the message as the name and the password as the content. Then when you wanted to open it you were supposed to enter the decrypted version of the password, and then somewhere around here I started rethinking it.

This with creating the file and so is still in the script, but how I intend it to work now is: You enter your message in the first text box, press the button and the message will be encrypted and a password will be created which also would be displayed. Which then also gets encrypted.

Then it should send this in the format of a dictionary over to a client. Then the client is processing this data sent by asking for the password decrypted and if it's correct it will decrypt the message. (The code below is only the server since I want to finish that first)

```
from tkinter import *
import os
import string
import random
import socket
import pickle

window = Tk()
window.title("Password Crypter")
window.configure(background="white")

def Server():
    HEADERSIZE = 10

    host = ''
    port = 50010

    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
        s.bind((host,port))
        s.listen(5)
        while True:
            conn, addr = s.accept()
            print(f"Connection fom {addr} has been established!")

            msg = pickle.dumps(d)

            msg = bytes(f'{len(msg):<{HEADERSIZE}}', "utf-8") + msg

            conn.send(msg)

def randomword(length):
    letters = string.ascii_lowercase
    global get
    get = ''.join(random.choice(letters) for i in range(length))
    print(get)

def click():
    global sample_string
    global inputText

    inputText = textEntry.get()

    encoder()

def click1():
    global inputText1

    inputText1 = textEntry1.get()

    accesDecoder()

def encoder():

    global sample_string
    global inputText
    
    sample_string = inputText.lower()
    char_to_replace = {'s': 'X',
                    'a': 'Y',
                    'i': 'Z',
                    'b': 'W',
                    'k': 'V',
                    'o': 'U',
                    'e': 'T',
                    'c': 'S',
                    'l': 'R',
                    'j': 'Q',
                    'h': 'P',
                    'm': 'O',
                    'r': 'N',
                    'd': 'M',
                    'q': 'L',
                    'u': 'K',
                    'p': 'J',
                    'y': 'I',
                    's': 'H',
                    'f': 'G',
                    'w': 'F',
                    't': 'E',
                    'n': 'D',
                    'x': 'C',
                    'r': 'B',
                    'v': 'A'}

    for key, value in char_to_replace.items():
        sample_string = sample_string.replace(key, value)
 
    Label (window, text=sample_string, bg="white", fg="black", font="none 12 bold") .grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=W)
    
    randomword(20)
    passCrypter()
    Label (window, textvariable=passwordVar, bg="white", fg="black", font="none 12 bold") .grid(row=4, column=0, sticky=W)
    passwordVar.set(get)
    with open(sample_string + '.txt', 'w') as messageFile:
        messageFile.write(sample_string2)
    add_element(d, sample_string, sample_string2)
    print(d)
    Server()

def add_element(dict, key, value):
    if key not in dict:
        dict[key] = []
    dict[key].append(value)

d = {}

passwordVar = StringVar()
decrypted = StringVar()
wrongCode = StringVar()

def accesDecoder():
    with open(sample_string + '.txt', 'r') as messageFile:
        global code
        code = messageFile.read()
    passDecrypt()
    if inputText1 == sample_string3 or inputText1 == sample_string:
        print("You have accesed the decoder.")
        decrypted.set('')
        decoder()
    else:
        Label (window, textvariable=decrypted, bg="white", fg="black", font="none 12 bold") .grid(row=4, column=1, sticky=W)
        decrypted.set("Wrong code, try again.")

def decoder():
    sample_string1 = sample_string
    char_to_replace1 = {'X': 's',
                    'Y': 'a',
                    'Z': 'i',
                    'W': 'b',
                    'V': 'k',
                    'U': 'o',
                    'T': 'e',
                    'S': 'c',
                    'R': 'l',
                    'Q': 'j',
                    'P': 'h',
                    'O': 'm',
                    'N': 'r',
                    'M': 'd',
                    'L': 'q',
                    'K': 'u',
                    'J': 'p',
                    'I': 'y',
                    'H': 's',
                    'G': 'f',
                    'F': 'w',
                    'E': 't',
                    'D': 'n',
                    'C': 'x',
                    'B': 'r',
                    'A': 'v'}

    for key, value in char_to_replace1.items():
        sample_string1 = sample_string1.replace(key, value)
    print(sample_string1)
    decrypted.set(sample_string1)
    Label (window, textvariable=decrypted, bg="white", fg="black", font="none 12 bold") .grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=W)

def passCrypter():
    global sample_string2
    
    sample_string2 = get
    char_to_replace2 = {'s': 'X',
                    'a': 'Y',
                    'i': 'Z',
                    'b': 'W',
                    'k': 'V',
                    'o': 'U',
                    'e': 'T',
                    'c': 'S',
                    'l': 'R',
                    'j': 'Q',
                    'h': 'P',
                    'm': 'O',
                    'r': 'N',
                    'd': 'M',
                    'q': 'L',
                    'u': 'K',
                    'p': 'J',
                    'y': 'I',
                    's': 'H',
                    'f': 'G',
                    'w': 'F',
                    't': 'E',
                    'n': 'D',
                    'x': 'C',
                    'r': 'B',
                    'v': 'A'}

    for key, value in char_to_replace2.items():
        sample_string2 = sample_string2.replace(key, value)

def passDecrypt():
    global sample_string3
    sample_string3 = code
    char_to_replace3 = {'X': 's',
                    'Y': 'a',
                    'Z': 'i',
                    'W': 'b',
                    'V': 'k',
                    'U': 'o',
                    'T': 'e',
                    'S': 'c',
                    'R': 'l',
                    'Q': 'j',
                    'P': 'h',
                    'O': 'm',
                    'N': 'r',
                    'M': 'd',
                    'L': 'q',
                    'K': 'u',
                    'J': 'p',
                    'I': 'y',
                    'H': 's',
                    'G': 'f',
                    'F': 'w',
                    'E': 't',
                    'D': 'n',
                    'C': 'x',
                    'B': 'r',
                    'A': 'v'}

    for key, value in char_to_replace3.items():
        sample_string3 = sample_string3.replace(key, value)

textEntry = Entry(window, width=60, bg="white")
textEntry.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)
Button(window, text="Submit Text", width=13, command=click) .grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W)

textEntry1 = Entry(window, width=60, bg="white")
textEntry1.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=W)
Button(window, text="Submit Code", width=13, command=click1) .grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=W)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: I would encourage you to edit your question to explain how the code is intended to be used. I ran it and a window pops up with two text boxes. What should I do? I typed something in one and then the program seemed to hang, so I gave up. Later I saw a `PZ.txt` file had been written and it contained an encrypted data structure. You need to explain the intended usage more explicitly.

Comment: Alright, will do

Comment: Changed it up, hopefully, you're able to understand what I mean.